# Calling an Oracle Stored Procedure in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to call an Oracle stored procedure from a C# program. I am using a `SYS_REFCURSOR` an the output of the stored procedure. I am getting invalid SQL error when I reach the line

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

in my C# program. I can't figure out why I am getting this invalid SQL error.

Here is the C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string custname;
        int custnbr;

        List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        string oradb = "User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Data Source=IP:PORT/xxxx;Pooling=false;";
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_TEST";

            OracleParameter oraP = new OracleParameter();
            oraP.ParameterName = "R_RECORDSET";
            oraP.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.RefCursor;
            oraP.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(oraP);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                custnbr = reader.GetInt32(0);
                custname = reader.GetString(1);
                Customer custTemp = new Customer(custnbr, custname);
                customers.Add(custTemp);
            }

            foreach (var cust in customers)
            {
                textBox1.AppendText("Customer Number: " + cust.custnbr + "\t");
                textBox1.AppendText("Customer Name: " + cust.custname + "\r\n");
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(ex.ToString());
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is the Oracle stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PROCEDURE_TEST 
(   R_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS 
BEGIN
OPEN R_RECORDSET FOR
SELECT POTCHARGECATEGORY, POTCHARGECODE, POTCHARGEDESCRIPTION,
       POTCHARGEBASEAMT, SUM(POTCHARGEQTY), SUM(POTCHARGEAMOUNT)

FROM riowner.ccum_customer customer

WHERE ic.collection_Datetime =
TO_DATE('30-SEP-2015 23:59:59','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')

GROUP BY POTCHARGECATEGORY, POTCHARGECODE, POTCHARGEDESCRIPTION,
         POTCHARGEBASEAMT;
END PROCEDURE_TEST;
```

Comment: `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;` should be 
`cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Comment: Can you run the procedure outside of .NET environment (for example, with SQLPLUS, SQL Developer, Toad, or Tora)?

Comment: I think something this obvious can be a comment but I will write it down as an answer @mason

Comment: Yes, the stored procedure works in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: @Shawn there is a difference between `Command.Text && Command.Type`

Comment: Thanks...cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; works!!!

Comment: if this works @Shawn please mark it as the acceptable answer Thanks !!

Answer (score 3):

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

should be

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: Actually, the `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text` line can be deleted because the code already sets the command type to stored procedure right after opening the connection.

Comment: which is true.. but the second assignment is overriding the first assignment so that's also a good catch @EdGibbs

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to MethodMan's answer, you should be able to keep the command type as Text, but change your SQL command to this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN PROCEDURE_TEST END;";
```

MethodMan's method is better if you just need to call one procedure, but the way I did it above would allow you to do more procedures, so it's something to be aware of in the future.

Comment: I agree as well with @Mason there are 2 ways to skin this cat +1

Comment: Hi this is incorrect, you need to add the semicolon like this  cmd.CommandText = "BEGIN PROCEDURE_TEST; END;";

OR "BEGIN PROCEDURE_TEST(1234); END;";

Comment: @Rob Are you sure? I no longer have access to Oracle to verify this.

Comment: @MethodMan Yes - tested on our Oracle version 12.