# How can I execute 2 SQLplus statements on the same 1 line C #

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I have 1 procedure that can be used on sqlplus but in C# I don't know how to write execute in cmd.commandtext

this is my command
sqlplus

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_column1 (p_MaritalStatus IN VARCHAR2,p_cursor out SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
BEGIN
   Open p_cursor for
   SELECT column_name FROM all_tab_columns WHERE table_name = p_MaritalStatus ORDER BY column_id;
   dbms_sql.return_result(p_cursor);
EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN 
NULL;
 END;

VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;
execute get_column1('V_$SGA',:cur);
```

c#

```
`OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;execute get_column1('V_$SGA',:cur);";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();`
```

Comment: Very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/3940587/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/33422233/1509264 (but the specific question of using two statements is different)

Answer (score 1):

When you set `CommandType` to `StoredProcedure`, that means that the `CommandText` contains ONLY the name of a stored procedure. Something like this:

```cs
cmd.CommandText = "get_column1";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Your command is NOT a stored procedure. It's inline SQL. The fact that that SQL invokes a stored procedure is neither here nor there. Just get rid of the line that sets `CommandType` and accept the default `Text`.

I don't really use Oracle so I'm still not 100% sure that it will work with multiple SQL statements separated by semicolons but the would work with SQL Server, so I'm guessing it will be fine.

EDIT:

According to a comment posted below, you cannot execute multiple statements together in a single command. In that case, you would presumably have use two separate commands or the same command twice and change the `CommandText` in between. You'd probably want to do so within a transaction. What I said about the `CommandType` still stands.

Comment: "would work with SQL Server, so I'm guessing it will be fine." **NO**, Oracle forbids multiple statements in a single command to help prevent SQL injection attacks so it is definitely not fine.

Comment: @MT0, I'll incorporate that into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle forbids multiple statements in a single command. This helps to prevent SQL injection attacks.

For your use case, do not try to declare the variable in SQL, specify the bind parameter in C#:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_column1 (
  p_MaritalStatus IN  all_tab_columns.table_name%TYPE,
  p_cursor        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
   OPEN p_cursor FOR
     SELECT column_name
     FROM   all_tab_columns
     WHERE  table_name = p_MaritalStatus
     ORDER BY column_id;
END;
/
```

Then (untested as I do not have a C# connected database but it gives you the general idea):

```c#
OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "get_column1";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_MARITALSTATUS", OracleDbType.Char).Value = "V_$SGA";
cmd.Parameters.Add("P_CURSOR", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```